# How to read, process and write large file in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a txt file with size 100GB. I have to read it, do some processing and write in the same order as in original file in the most fastest way. For reading and writing I couldn't use multiprocessing, for processing I have tried map but I've got memory overflow, I've also tried with imap but it seems not speeding the process.

Comment: see this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-large-text-files-in-python/

Comment: It depends on the content of the file and what your "some processing" does. You can open a file and read it line by line and do the processing the same way, so you never have the file completely in memory.

Comment: Please clarify what processing you need to do.

Comment: I have text.txt file, and by processing I mean str.replace and this kind of stuff.

Comment: If speed of processing is a major concern, and your processing consists of substitutions and similar, you'd very likely be considerably better off using `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load the file into memory all at once, but read it line by line. Don't store the output into memory all at once, but write it line by line. In the most basic form:

```
with open('input.txt', 'rt') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'wt') as output_file:
        for input_line in input_file:
            output_line = process(input_line)
            # Assuming that output_line will have a trailing newline.
            output_file.write(output_line)
```

If the processing is very CPU-intensive, you could gain performance with parallelization. But the I/O will have to remain sequential, so it's only worth it if you see that the program is taking 100% of a CPU core.

Comment: To the down-voter... whilst you are welcome and obviously entitled to down-vote, it is generally appreciated if you leave a comment explaining **why** so that we can all learn and benefit from your knowledge/experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about "speeding it up" for now, if you have to process a 100GB file your issue should be memory consumption. Your first issue is getting it to work **at all**.

You cannot read the whole file into memory, then process it (unless you happen to have 100GB RAM). You have to either read it line by line, or in batches and process only parts at a time.

So, instead of using `file.read()`, use `file.readline()` or `file.read(some_size)`, depending on what that file that you read.

In the same way, if you need to write a processed 100GB file, don't collect all results in a list or something, write each line to the result file as soon as you are done processing a line of the original file.

Incidentally, I would expect this to the fastest method with your requirements (same order), because you can forget doing anything out of order and then sorting. You can't sort the data in-place if it's too big for your memory, and while sorting it on the file system is possible, it's more complicated and I am somewhat doubtful it would be faster.