# Open 140GB .txt file in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, txt

I have a huge dna sequence saved in a .txt file of size 140GB that I would like to open using a txt file editor. Notepad, Python, R don't allow to open such a file. Is there a dedicated text file editor to open large files?

I am currently using this code in Python to open the 140GB large file .txt file:

```
path = open("my_file_path\my_140GB_file.txt", "r")
file = path.read()
print(file)
```

The error message is `MemoryError` referring to `file = path.read()`

Comment: And what is your question? Loading the entire document at once is not feasible with something like `read()` on a file object, you can instead read parts of it incrementally, either by line, character, or byte and split them up as you'd like

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I added more informations to the question to clarify my issue

Comment: Python can open a file of any size. Show us the Python code you are using that you think will not open the file. I would guess that you are using a high-level function that opens the file and then attempts to  read it all into memory. That will obviously not work, in any language.

Comment: Thank you, I added the python code I am using to open the 140GB .txt file

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into-memory

Comment: I can't mark this question as duplicate because the other question has no accepted answer, but here you go, this applies to you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71139812/1319284

Comment: @d.cio It's still unclear _what you're trying to achieve_ - you can't display 140GB worth of text at once anyway (where would you find a screen big enough?), so what do you want to _do_ with it?

Comment: Apparently (?), this is not a python question. It is a question about windows text editors. Please update your question. There is no such thing as any text 'editor' that can open a file that big. Linux tools such as `less` can show you file of practically any size as it doesn't read the whole thing in either. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/159521/503621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a multiple of ways to read large text files in Python.  If it is a delimited file, you might want to use the pandas library.

You can use a context manager and read chunks as follows.

**Python 3.8+**

```
with open("my_file_path\my_140GB_file.txt", "r") as f:
    while chunk := f.read(1024 * 10):   # you can use any chunk size you want
        do_something(chunk)
```

**Before Python 3.8**

You can iterate with a lambda:

```
with open("my_file_path\my_140GB_file.txt", "rb") as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda:f.read(1024*10), ""):
        do_something(chunk)
```

Or, if the file is line based, you can read each line.

```
with open("my_file_path\my_140GB_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

**Pandas DataFrame for delimited files**

If your file is delimited (like a csv), then you might consider using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
for chunk in pd.read_csv("my_file_path\my_140GB_file.csv", chunksize=2):
    do_something(chunk )
```